# Php and mysql, missing first row

Tags: php, mysql, row

I need a little help.
This code miss the first row, I don't know the reason.
I've searched a lot around the web but everyone talk about the mysql_fetch_array($results) but there's nothing similar in my code.

Do you find something wrong in this code?

```
<?php 

// create query 
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";

// execute query 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 

$id = mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
$name = mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
$imageurl = mysql_result($result,$i,"imageurl");
$price = mysql_result($result,$i,"price");
$quantity = mysql_result($result,$i,"quantity");

// see if any rows were returned 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    // yes 
    // print them one after another 
    echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
    echo "<thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Image</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td>".$id."</td><td>".$name."</td><td><a href='".$imageurl."' class='fancybox fancybox-effects-e' title='".$name."'><img src='".$imageurl."' alt='".$name."'></a></td><td>€ ".$price."</td><td>".$quantity."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "</table>"; 
} 
else { 
    // no 
    // print status message 
    echo "No rows found!"; 
} 

// free result set memory 
mysql_free_result($result); 

// close connection 
mysql_close($connection); 

?>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM products` is your query.. how do you know what is supposed to be your first row when you don't use any ordering?

Comment: In the row where you assign `$id`, you reference `$i`. Where was `$i` assigned a value?

Comment: Where do you initialise `$i`? You initialise `$id`, but never re-set it when you're looping through your results, so it's only ever going to output the same value. (ditto for the other four variables)

Answer (score 3):

Note this message on the PHP page for [mysql_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php)

```
Calls to mysql_result() should not be mixed with calls to other functions that deal with the result set.
```

This is going to advance your record pointer past the first result so your calls to mysql_fetch_array are going to be off by one.

Anyway I think what you are after is

```
<?php 

// create query 
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";

// execute query 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 

// see if any rows were returned 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    // yes 
    // print them one after another 
    echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
    echo "<thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Image</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td><a href='".$row["imageurl"]."' class='fancybox fancybox-effects-e' title='".$row["name"]."'><img src='".$row["imageurl"]."' alt='".$row["name"]."'></a></td><td>€ ".$row["price"]."</td><td>".$row["quantity"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "</table>"; 
} 
else { 
    // no 
    // print status message 
    echo "No rows found!"; 
} 

// free result set memory 
mysql_free_result($result); 

// close connection 
mysql_close($connection); 

?>
```

Comment: `$id` and `$name` should also be elements of `$row`: `$row['id']` and `$row['name']`.